# Are there any differences between `import a.b as b` and `b=a.b` in Python?

Tags: python

Are ther any differences between the following two code?

1.

```
import torch.nn as nn
```

2.

```
import torch
nn = torch.nn
```

Comment: in the first option you are importing `torch.nn` and changing the name, in the second you are creating a variable with the value `torch.nn`, without knowing that it is torch and nn could not be indicated if it generates problems or not,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `nn` is a submodule and `torch/__init__.py` does not import it, the variable assignment method will fail.

If either fails, they do so with different exceptions: the import statement raises `ImportError` and the variable assignment raises `AttributeError`.